# How I mock `httpx.connectError` using httpx-pytest package?

Tags: python, pytest, httpx

I want to mock ConnectionError for my API. I'm creating a python package for one software which if running on `localhost:8080` then it will give result correctly. But if the software is not running, then I want to catch it. I'm able to write function using `httpx.ConnectError` to get this exception, but how can I write test for the same ?

my function is like this

```
def get_workspace(self, workspace: str) -> Union[WorkspaceModel, GSResponse]:
        try:
            Client = self.http_client
            responses = Client.get(f"workspaces/{workspace}")
            if responses.status_code == 200:
                return WorkspaceModel.parse_obj(responses.json())
            else :
                results = self.response_recognise(responses)
                return results
        except httpx.TimeoutException as exc:
            res = {}
            res['code'] = 504
            res['response'] = "Timeout Error"
            return GSResponse.parse_obj(res)
        except httpx.NetworkError as exc:
            res = {}
            res['code'] = 503
            res['response'] = "Geoserver unavailable"
            return GSResponse.parse_obj(res)
```

Comment: please show the function definition of the function that needs to be tested

Comment: Hi, I have added function

Answer (score 1):

Using [pytest-httpx](https://github.com/Colin-b/pytest_httpx), you can simulate httpx raising any kind of exception thanks to [httpx_mock.add_exception](https://github.com/Colin-b/pytest_httpx#raising-exceptions).

Your test case would look something like that:

```
import httpx
import pytest
from pytest_httpx import HTTPXMock


def test_exception_raising(httpx_mock: HTTPXMock):
    httpx_mock.add_exception(httpx.ConnectError())

    # Your code performing the http call here.
```